# Inner Join not giving unique values mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have 2 Tables :

Table 1:
[image]
Table 2:
[image]

Want to join the tables and get the sum of the timetaken and duration field.
The Query tried is :

```
select distinct 
  table1.city , 
  FORMAT(SUM(time_to_sec(table1.timetaken))/3600,2) as TT, 
  count(table1.city) as C1, 
  FORMAT(SUM(time_to_sec(table2.duartion))/3600 ,2) as D, 
  count(table2.city) as C2
from table1
inner join table2 on table1.city= table2.city  
group by city;
```

But got the output something  as:
[image]

But the expected output is:
[image]

If Inner Join is not the right way to do , can someone correct me to achieve the EXPECTED OUTPUT ?
Thanks a lot.!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 rows with city `ABC` in table 1 and 2 rows with `ABC` in table2 . So of course, an inner join of those two will have 6 rows (each `ABC` from table1 is joined with each `ABC` in table2) same for `PQR`

From you examle data, I suppose, you want something like that (ie group each table separately and then join the results)

```
with 
  g1(city, tt, c1) 
  as (select city, sum(time_to_sec(timetaken)), count(*) from table1 group by city),
  g2(city, dur, c2) 
  as (select city, sum(time_to_sec(duration)), count(*) from table2 group by city)

select g1.city, format(tt / 3600, 2), c1 , format(dur / 3600, 2), c2
from g1 inner join g2 on g1.city = g2.city
```

The query is from the top of the head so there may be some syntactic issues, but you should get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT city , 
             FORMAT(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(timetaken))/3600,2) AS TT, 
             COUNT(city) AS C1 
        FROM table1 GROUP BY city) AS T1
INNER JOIN 
   (SELECT city,
           FORMAT(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(Duration))/3600 ,2) AS D, 
           COUNT(city) AS C2 FROM table2 GROUP BY city) AS T2 
ON T1.city= T2.city;
```

Perform the calculation on each table then make them as subqueries. You can `INNER JOIN` them afterwards in the outer query.

Answer (score 0):

I think the combination of distinct, sum, group and joins is a bit too much. I haven't tested it, but it looks like you will not be getting all the rows that you expect. It might already be solved by just removing the distinct keyword (due to the sum and and the group by you basically have the distinctive cities already). Otherwise, what you could try is using sub queries to first make the sums over the different cities in the two tables and join those two sub queries together.